# How to Remove All Elements of a Dynamically Allocated Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I need to make a function to delete all elements of a dynamically allocated array (found in my program's default constructor), and I am wondering how to do so. A function to remove any element at any index was already provided for me:

```
template<typename elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::removeAt(int location) {
    if (location < 0 || location >= length) {
        cout << "The location of the item to be removed ";
        cout << "is out of range." << endl;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = location; i < length - 1; ++i) {
            list[i] = list[i + 1];
        }
        --length;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can use this method as a way to remove every element to make the size 0?

Comment: Remove the last element repeatedly until `length` is 0. Better would be to just set `length` to 0 if you can.

Comment: `while (length > 0) { removeAt(length - 1); }`

Comment: What the type of `list` here? Do you want to deallocate the memory you created or just not use them since what your `removeAt` does is shifting the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the elements of `list` past `length` are copies of the "live" elements, the simplest way would be to set length to 0.

```
template<typename elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::removeAll() {
    length = 0
}
```

The naive way of implementing it in terms of  `removeAt` is to remove the first element until there are none left

```
template<typename elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::removeAll() {
    while (length) removeAt(0);
}
```

However that will do a bunch of unnecessary copying, so it's more effective to remove the last element each time

```
template<typename elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::removeAll() {
    while (length) removeAt(length-1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To just delete the whole array you can use `delete[] arr;`
And if you want to just delete each element, you can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
    delete arr[i];
}
```